# Issue using ActivatedRoute parameter in HTTP Get request

Tags: angular

I'm having problems getting a parameter from ActivatedRoute to use for a Http Get request. Basically, I'm trying to get this.link and use it on my DataService to make the Http Get request. When a user visits the DetailsComponent, I wan't to use that route parameter to form the Http get request. For example, a user navigates to example.com/animal/cat, I want to use cat in my Get request. However, every time I try, I receive a response telling me this.link is undefined.

```
GET http://123.123.123.123/api/v2/_table/animal/undefined?related=move_by…k&api_key=7201dd61c71 404 (Not Found)
```

DataService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Subscription, Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor(private dataService: Http) {
  }
  urlprefix = 'http://123.123.123.123/api/v2/_table/animal/';
  api = '&api_key=7201dd61c71';

  getData(url): Observable<any> {
    return this.dataService.get(this.urlprefix + url + this.api);
  }
}
```

DetailComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import { DataService } from '../../data.service';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'animal-details',
  templateUrl: 'animal-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['animal-details.component.css'],
  directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers:[DataService]
})
export class AnimalDetailsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private subscription: Subscription;

  animal = {};

  link: string;
  table = 'animal/'
  private url = this.table + this.link + '?related=family';



  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private dataService: DataService, private router: Router) {
    this.subscription = activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
    (param: any) => this.link = param['link']
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.dataService.getData(this.url)
    .map((response: Response) => response.json())
    .subscribe(
      (data: any) => {this.animal = data},
      err => { this.router.navigate(['error404']) }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

I can see the params clearly being outputted properly in the DetailsComponent via string interpolation: {{link}}. No matter what I try though, it still shows as undefined in the Get request and I'm always given an error. I'd appreciate any help.

Edit: new working code below
DataService:

```
export class DataService {

  constructor(private dataService: Http) {
  }
  urlprefix = 'http://123.123.123.123/api/v2/_table/';
  api = '&api_key=7201dd61c71';

  getData(table, link, url): Observable<any> {
    return this.dataService.get(this.urlprefix + table + link + url +this.api);
  }
}
```

AnimalDetailsComponent:

```
link: string;
table = 'animal/';
private url = '?related=family';

ngOnInit() {

  this.dataService.getData(this.table, this.link, this.url)
  .map((response: Response) => response.json())
  .subscribe(
    (data: any) => {this.animal = data},
    err => { this.router.navigate(['error404']) }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what is the route url for your details component? If you are calling the details with query parameter, example **http://localhost/details?id=123**, then please replace ? with ;, new router use ; in url (**http://localhost/details;id=123**).

Then in your **AnimalDetailsComponent** move `this.subscription...` to the beginning of **ngInit()**. Routing initialize in during Angular life cycle, not during constructor.

Comment: `{ path: 'animal/:link', component: AnimalDetailsComponent }`

I'm not using query Parameters, I'm using Route Parameters. I assumed that since the constructor is completes before ngOnInit, I could assign the route parameter to the variable 'link' then ngOnInit would use it on the Get Http request via DataService. I tried assigning the value 'cat' to 'link' and it worked just as I thought it would. Still shows as 'Undefined' when the constructor assigns the value however.

Comment: No, it's not during construction, constructtor is not withing the Angular2 life cycle. Move your code `this.subscription = ....` to ngInit instead.

Comment: I tried moving the code in the constructor to the ngOnInit method, the link property was still undefined in the Get request. I managed to come up with a solution though. I'll post it here incase someone else might run into something similar. I'm still a beginner in angular2 so there is probably better ways.

I moved the link property from the url property directly into the getData method as an argument. Works flawless now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Sal Could you please share the solution you implemented. I need to implement the same for angular 4. Thanks